# Why is the union of x-axis and y-axis closed under scalar multiplication but not addition?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been looking to understand linear algebra(vector spaces and subspaces) from different sources, then I came across the statement " the union of x-axis and y-axis" to the question "Give a set that is closed under scalar multiplication but not addition". I don't really understand how

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know how or why the union of x-axis and y-axis is closed under scalar multiplication but not addition

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Strong suggestion: consider $(1, 0) + (0, 1).$

Comment: Hint: what is the union of the x and y axis?

Comment: I've tried to add two arbitrary x,y coordinate, say (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), the addition is not commutative for all x, y values. that's what i think but i don't know if that is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The union of the x and y axsis is the set $S = \{(x,0)\cup(0,y)|x,y\in \mathbb R\}$

If we multiply a vector in this set by scalar $a$ we get $(ax,0)$ or $(0,ay)$ and both of these are in $S.$  This is closure under scalar multiplication.

But if we add $(x,0) + (0,y)$ with $x,y \ne 0$ we get $(x,y)$ which is not in $S.$

Comment: Oh! i get it now, i misinterpreted the union for addition. This was really helpful!